# Как сделать такой функционал?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Делаю такой мокап с переключателем. Всю логику продумал, все легко. Осталось лишь сделать один маленький пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно на изображение, сделал своими руками. Все очень просто, есть родительский блок который ограничен рамками макбука (Только экран без рамок). И есть это полоска. Она центрируется через `position: absolute;`. На скриншоте имеет `left: 55%;`. `left: 0;` - граница изображения.

Вопрос, как сделать чтобы лишь при клике на саму полоску можно было передвигать ее позицию по X, без минусовых позиций и не дальше чем граница (чтобы ограничевали 0 и 100%)?

Comment: а можно ваш код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, как вариант так [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shelukhin89/wfxo1u5c/1/)

```js
$('.poloska').click(function() {
  var p = parseInt($(this).css('left')) * 100 / $('body').width();
  p >= 50 ? $(this).animate({
    left: '5%'
  }, 500) : $(this).animate({
    left: '95%'
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.poloska {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 70%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="poloska"></div>
```